# Crear un ejecutable con ptyhon cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy creando un ejecutable con python usando la librería `cx_freeze`, pero tengo un problema, al ejecutar el `setup.py` para crear el .exe este me tira un error pidiéndome cerrar Python 2.7:

```
  Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  python.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 0.0.0.0
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: 56634a05
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    ntdll.dll
```

En el error que se muestra en un pop-up desde `cx_freeze`:

```
  cx_Freeze Fatal Error

  cannot get zipimporter instance
```

No estoy encontrando la solución, ya que en muchos foros dicen que puede ser problema de actualización del SO - Windows 7- (controladores o drivers).

Por el momento no pongo el script de `setup.py` para no confundir e irse por las ramas.

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que muestres también tu `setup.py`, mientras mas información, mejor.

Comment: No responde a tu pregunta, pero prueba http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: @astrojuanlu lo estuve probando y funciono perfecto, pero tengo un problema... estoy usando `kinterbasdb`,cuando ejecuto el .exe y quiero generar la conexión con firebird, no lo hace. Estimo que no me esta reconociendo la librería `kinterbasdb` . Saludos

Comment: El error estaba en la llamada al  icono del programa con  cx_freeze @César , pero ahora tengo ese problema aun mayor y es la conexión con `kinterbasdb`. Creo el archivo .exe, coloco las librerías correspondientes del .py, pero nada. No puedo lograr la conexión con firebird con el .exe, pero con Mysql si, eso es lo que descoloca y hace de pensar que hay algún tipo de problema con la librería `kinterbasdb` o tal vez la codificacion de los caracteres que lleva la conexión. Quiero aclarar que si ejecuto el archivo .py desde la consola llamando a python `>>python con.py` funciona perfecto.   **:(**

Comment: [SOLUCIONADO] La solución estaba en algo tan simple que leyendo con tranquilidad el data book de la librería el problema no hubiese aparecido.Resulta que estaba incluyendo las librerías en `includes = [,"kinterbasdb","csv", "operator","MySQLdb"] 
` y no en `
packages = ["kinterbasdb","MySQLdb"]` ..Saludos y gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: @DarioSanchez bien! Recuerda que puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y aceptarla luego, la idea es que las preguntas no queden sueltas y funcionen como referencias para otras personas. Saludos

Comment: @César como le agregas el solucionado al tema?

Comment: @DarioSanchez a lo que me refiero es que esto no es como un foro que editas el título con "[SOLUCIONADO]", las preguntas van a seguir como no solucionadas mientras no tengan una respuesta aceptada. Más abajo vas a ver que puedes crear una respuesta a tu propia pregunta.

Comment: @César ok gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución estaba en algo tan simple que leyendo con tranquilidad el data book de la librería el problema no hubiese aparecido.

Resulta que estaba incluyendo las librerías en:

```
includes = ["kinterbasdb","csv", "operator","MySQLdb"]
```

Y no en:

```
packages = ["kinterbasdb","MySQLdb"]
```

Comment: Perfecto, no olvides regresar luego para marcar tu propia pregunta como aceptada, así la pregunta queda como resuelta.